# Crop an image in Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, crop

I have an image and I need to crop it. I also have the coordinates. How should I crop the image and get cropped image `base64` code?

Comment: it can be tricky. I think you better find some plugins for this purpose.

Comment: I use this cropper but I think it just returns the coordinates. I need to save the image to server and I dont want to do the cropping process in code behind. http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/